# GLES20.glUniform1f doesn't work, but const do

Tags: java, android

As a base to use shaders I've used this project:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1007973/Basic-Shader-Programming-on-Android

Now, I've added another shader to the others and it just gives me a black screen. I don't see any errors in logs. It uses some extra parameters (uniforms), like this for example:

```
uniform float scale;
```

In `public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)` I've added:

```
GLES20.glUniform1f(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(g_hShader, "scale"), 1.0f);
```

Well, it doesn't work.

But replacing it with:

```
const float scale = 1.;
```

in shader file makes it working again.

Here's the whole shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;

//const float aspectRatio = 1.5;
//const vec2 center = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
//const float radius = 0.5;
//const float scale = 1.;

uniform float aspectRatio;
uniform vec2 center;
uniform float radius;
uniform float scale;

void main()
{
    vec2 textureCoordinateToUse = vec2(v_TexCoordinate.x, (v_TexCoordinate.y * aspectRatio + center.y - center.y * aspectRatio));
    float dist = distance(center, textureCoordinateToUse);
    textureCoordinateToUse = v_TexCoordinate;
    if (dist < radius)
    {
        textureCoordinateToUse -= center;
        float percent = 1.0 - ((radius - dist) / radius) * scale;
        percent = percent * percent;
        textureCoordinateToUse = textureCoordinateToUse * percent;
        textureCoordinateToUse += center;
    }
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, textureCoordinateToUse);
}
```

Where's the problem? I've tried moving

```
GLES20.glUniform1f(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(g_hShader, "scale"), 1.0f);
```

to a different locations in onDrawFrame and it didn't work. As far as I know it should be the right place to pass uniform parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the error lies in that the program object is not used currently.

If you are switching shaders, you have to call `glUseProgram(g_hShader)` every time before you are doing uniform calls.

It is also no wonder that you do not see anything, scale is set to 0.0 in that case. You should check the result of `glGetUniformLocation`. If it returns -1, you know there is a problem.

Edit:

After seeing the code:

This is a problem here. The black color is caused by the fact that the texture unit is not bound. Both values are texHandle

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0)        
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texHandle);        
GLES20.glUniform1i(texHandle, 0);
```

There might be more problems, but checking more code would not fit the format of this site. Hope I could help.

Comment: First, there's GLES20.glUseProgram(g_hShader); at the top of onDrawFrame. Second, I'm passing 1.0f, so why are you saying it's 0.0? Third, I've checked glGetUniformLocation and it indeed returns -1 :(

Comment: You can try downloading project from codeproject and replace code of any shader with mine. Then in GLRenderer.java there's onDrawFrame function I'm talking about.

Comment: 'I have  added another shader' -> It means, you need to have another shaderprogram too, if you want to use both of them at the same time. If the uniform location returns -1, the value passed in does not matter. You get a 0 value in the shader, if nothing is set.

Comment: Can you try running the project from the link I posted above? It's like 2 mins to add a new shader to the list. I do have another shaderprogram, of course. I don't use 2 shaders at the same time. Without parameters, using const values, shader works fine. The problem is why glGetUniformLocation returns -1 and how to fix this.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to make it run on my device and claim it works. You might just overlook something in your code. My help is only relevant, if I am commenting on your code. I can of course take a look on your code if you post a github link.

Comment: Strange, now it returns 1, not -1, but it still doesn't work. Here's github repo: https://github.com/piotrros/BulgeShader Just run the app and switch effect to the last one (Bulge), this is the one I've added.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the problem with the code above? How to fix this?

Comment: One should be a texture position the other one the texture you have loaded in. You can check other answers regarding texture binding.